# `circe` Type-level Json => A Function?

Tags: scala, argonaut, circe

Using `circe` or `argonaut`, how can I write a `Json => A` (note - `Json` may not be the name of the type) where `A` is given by the `SSN` class:

```
  // A USA Social Security Number has exactly 8 digits.
  case class SSN(value: Sized[List[Nat], _8])
```

?

Pseudocode:

`// assuming this function is named f`

`f(JsArray(JsNumber(1)))` would fail to become an `A` since its size is 1, whereas

`f(JsArray(JsNumber(1), ..., JsNumber(8)))` === `SSN(SizedList(1,...,8))`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number https://www.ssa.gov/policy/docs/ssb/v69n2/v69n2p55.html

Comment: Haha - good catch.  9 digit ssn, not 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

circe doesn't (currently) provide instances for `Sized`, but it probably should. In any case you can write your own pretty straightforwardly:

```
import cats.data.Xor
import io.circe.{ Decoder, DecodingFailure }
import shapeless.{ Nat, Sized }
import shapeless.ops.nat.ToInt
import shapeless.syntax.sized._

implicit def decodeSized[L <: Nat, A](implicit
  dl: Decoder[List[A]],
  ti: ToInt[L]
): Decoder[Sized[List[A], L]] = Decoder.instance { c =>
  dl(c).flatMap(as =>
    Xor.fromOption(as.sized[L], DecodingFailure(s"Sized[List[A], _${ti()}]", c.history))
  )
}
```

I've restricted this to `List` representations, but you could make it more generic if you wanted.

Now you can write your `SSN` instance like this (note that I'm using `Int` instead of `Nat` for the individual numbers, since once you've got something statically typed as a `Nat` it's not worth much):

```
case class SSN(value: Sized[List[Int], Nat._8])

implicit val decodeSSN: Decoder[SSN] = Decoder[Sized[List[Int], Nat._8]].map(SSN(_))
```

And then:

```
scala> import io.circe.jawn.decode
import io.circe.jawn.decode

scala> decode[SSN]("[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]")
res0: cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error,SSN] = Right(SSN(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)))

scala> decode[SSN]("[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]")
res1: cats.data.Xor[io.circe.Error,SSN] = Left(DecodingFailure(Sized[List[A], _8], List()))
```

If you really want a `Json => SSN` you could do this:

```
val f: Json => SSN = Decoder[SSN].decodeJson(_).valueOr(throw _)
```

But that's not really idiomatic use of circe.

Comment: Thanks, Travis. For those interested in this question, you might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183907/class-with-list-of-nats-between-0-and-2 interesting too. I'm trying to refine the usage of `List[Int]` to `List[A]` where `A` consists of `Nat'`s less than or equal to 2.